# returning a reference to an array vs a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I'm learning c++, and my textbook (c++ primer) proposes this example:

```
int odd[] = {1,3,5,7,9};
int even[] = {0,2,4,6,8};
// returns a pointer to an array of five int elements
auto arrPtr(int i) -> int(*)[5]
{ return (i%2) ? &odd : &even;}
```

and as an exerices asks to change the function so that it returns a reference to an array:

```
auto arrPtr(int i) -> int(&)[5]
{ return (i%2) ? odd : even;}
```

What I don't understand is why you have to return the array object in order to convert it to a reference to that array (if I'm understanding the code correctly). Shouldn't a memory address of an array "fit" perfectly in a reference type ?

Comment: No, a reference isn't an address. It is an alias for an existing object.

Comment: Because a reference to T is initialized using an object of type T, not a pointer to T.

Comment: Just add this: `template <class T> operator T& (T* j) { return *j; }` (Joking. Do not actually do this.)

Comment: Isn't a reference just an address? Isn't an address just an integer? Isn't an integer just a bunch of bits? The answer is "yes, at *some* level of abstraction". C++ happens to operate at a different level of abstraction.

Comment: `int(&)[5]` *is* a reference type; it's a reference to an array of extent 5 of type int.

Comment: I understand, thanks user657267 and @n.m. for a deeper understanding. I'm new to SO so sorry if it's a stupid questions, but why are these answers in the comment section?

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is why you have to return the array object in order to convert it to a reference to that array (if I'm understanding the code correctly).

Because that's how you initialise a reference: by specifying the object it refers to, with no extra adornments. Pointers are initialised from other pointers, which is why you need `&` to take the address of an object, yielding a pointer.

> Shouldn't a memory address of an array "fit" perfectly in a reference type ?

Yes, references are typically implemented in the same way as pointers. But why should that affect their syntax? They're conceptually different things (an alternative name for an object, not a value containing an address) with different syntax.

Comment: Exactly: a pointer is not what a reference __is__, but only what it is (usually) made of (to paraphrase CS Lewis).